# Is it possible to Merge Text Together?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, transforms, scale

I want to know if it is possible to **Merge Texts** together for easy to move, scale and grab with the **Objects**. For example; the **Fs** and **Frankfort Stainlesscoin** to be merged as one. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: You could parent one text object to the other (Ctrl+P) then move them both by moving the parent. Scaling works too, but it might not behave as expected.

Comment: I actually used this earlier when I first selected **Frankfort Stainlesscoin** then selected **Fs** last also applied (Ctrl+P) to make parent, and thereby un-select all. Finally, I selected the first as mentioned above, but it moved without the other. 

But now I selected the last and tried to move it, then it worked. At least I can now manage it as you said that 'it might not behave as anticipated'.

Comment: The other option (I don't know how feasible it is for you), is to convert the text objects to meshes (right click on them and select "convert to mesh), and then you could combine them into one object with Ctrl+J

Comment: I selected both texts, but didn't know how to convert them to Mesh, but is there any keyboard shortcut for the convert, since I know how to join Objects together with (Ctrl+J)?

Comment: You have to do them one at a time. Select it in object mode, right click and select "convert to mesh". Or you can select "object" at the top of the viewport, then select "Convert to" and then "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text"

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, Alright, the 'Convert to' was hidden at the top, whereas the keyboard shortcut is (Alt+C). It is now done.